# how to Extend a module from inet?

Tags: omnet++, inet

There are n Adhoc nodes that are deployed randomly in field. Because of necessity  to a special node I ought to extend new node from `AdhocHost` and add some parameter like node coordinates.

**MySensorNode.ned**

```
import inet.node.inet.AdhocHost;
import inet.node.inet.INetworkNode;

module MySensorNode extends AdhocHost like INetworkNode
{
  parameters:
      @display("bgb=827.48,663.192;bgu=m;i=misc/transmission_anim");
      @class(inet::MySensorNode);
}
```

**MySensorNode.h**

```
#ifndef __INET_MYSENSORNODE_H
#define __INET_MYSENSORNODE_H


namespace inet {

class MySensorNode : public ***????????what should I write here????***
{
   public:
    bool first_init = true;
        MySensorNode();
        virtual ~MySensorNode();
        virtual void initialize(int stage);
        virtual void changecolor();
        virtual void handleMessage(cMessage *msg);
        ?????????others ?????????

};
} // namespace inet
#endif /* __INET_MYSENSORNODE_H */
```

**MySensorNode.cc**

```
#include "MySensorNode.h"
namespace inet {

Define_Module(MySensorNode);


void MySensorNode::initialize(int stage)
{
    if(first_init)
    {
        changecolor();
    }
}

void MySensorNode::changecolor()
{
???????????????????
}


} // namespace inet
```

as the first part of question, I want to change  5% of nodes' color  in initialization. How can I do that?

**please mention my mistakes in the codes above. Thx**

Comment: Well, if you have 100 nodes and you want to change the color of 5%, why not taking the first five nodes (based on the node's ID) and change the color?

Comment: thank you @thardes2. actually it's the first step for clustering. nodes are deployed randomly and IDs aren't in order , the number of nodes are around 1000, and in the next step I want to choose nodes with more energy as Cluster head and change their color.

Comment: So your question is "how to change a nodes' color"?

Comment: as the first step yes, It's just a question to learn how to work with ad hoc node. I don't know it. In manual there is just cSimpleModule example but here I extend a module.

Comment: suppose I add a parameter like xpos to mysensornode module, how can I call it in any method()?

Answer (score 0):

If it is just about changing the colour, you need to change the Display String.

You could do it like this in the initialize method of the `UDPBasicApp` module (stage 1):

```
getParentModule()->getDisplayString().setTagArg("i", 1, "yellow");
```

The different tags are described in the OMNeT++ [Manual](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#cha:display-strings)

The `AdhocHost` is a compound module. Although the C++ class for a compound module can be overridden with the @class property, this is a feature that should probably never be used. Encapsulate the code into a simple module, and add it as a submodule. Read [this](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:ned-lang:compound-modules) for more information.

To add it as a submodule, you need to change the compound module. This could be done like this:

```
module SomeName extends AdhocHost 
{
    submodules:
        mySensorNode: MySensorNode;
}
```

Then your `MySensorNode` is a `cSimpleModule`:

```
namespace inet {

class MySensorNode : public cSimpleModule
{
   public:
....
```

There are a lot of examples for this on Stack Overflow and in the INET Framework, e.g. the `inet.linklayer.common.WirelessNic`

Comment: thanks. From which class I should define MySensorNode ? Is there any mistake in 3 codes? In general, I did not understand your answer. Could you plz describe more?

Comment: Oh sorry, then I got your question wrong. I edited my answer.

Comment: thanks, what does "Encapsulate the code into a simple module" mean? Is there any similar example ? could you mention the mistakes in .h and .cc files please?

Comment: There are a lot of example for this on Stack Overflow and in the INET Framework. I edited my post and added an example.